# Create new schema from zod schema after transformations

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I'm wondering if there's any functionality in Zod (or 3rd party as last resort) that creates a new Zod schema based on an existing schema after transformations has been applied (meaning the output of that schema).

For example if I have the Zod schema:

```
const schema = z.object({
  description: z.string().transform(s => s === "" ? undefined : s)
});
```

This schema would expect an object with a description as a string. However I would like to easily get the transformed schema, in this case it would look something like this:

```
const schemaAfterTransformations = z.object({
  description: z.string().optional()
});
```

I imagined it would be possible but perhaps I'm wrong and it's as difficult as generating a schema based on types.

Comment: I ended up not depending on a schema after transformations but rather persisted the data as it was before the transformations (I was building a cache made of aggregated data). To maintain the schema with existing transformations elsewhere in the code and also be able to validate the aggregated data without transformations, I ended up creating a schema without the transformations (called the input schema). Then I created a schema with transformations extending the input schema (called the output schema) using Zod's extend function.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible, since at no point is it encoded at runtime that your transform returns `string | undefined` (the compiler knows it of course). It's a feature I potentially need as well (but I'll likely need to write the code myself).